# Script to rename pc to string+serial number

Tags: powershell, cmd, rename

Im trying to write a simple script to rename each pc on the network to PC-RV- and the serial number. So for example PC-RV-DHXS970. I have found the article on how to rename a PC to the serial, ie. 
powershell rename-computer (gwmi win32_bios).serialnumber

However, I want to go a step farther and add the "PC-RV-" to the front of it. I have tryed: powershell rename-computer "PC-RV-"(gwmi win32_bios).serialnumber 
with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try: "PC-RV-"+(gwmi win32_bios).serialnumber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$NewName = "PC-RV-$((gwmi win32_bios).serialnumber)"
Rename-Computer -ComputerName 'OLDPCNAME' -NewName $NewName
```

The `gwmi` call is wrapped in `$()` which evaulates the command within the string.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't get it to work as a powershell script because of some permissions issues, but I was able to modify it a bit and make a batch file That i will run locally on each pc. powershell rename-computer "PC-RV-$((gwmi win32_bios).serialnumber)"
pause